How can I solve the overwrite error when downloading exercism.io exercises?
I signed up on exercism.io and wanted to download the first exercise into my GitHub repository folder. After installing the Exercism CLI and entering my token, I used the following command to download the exercise into the repository folder:
exercism download --track=python --exercise=hello-world

However, I encountered the following error:
Error: directory 'C:\Users\MJ\Exercism\python\hello-world' already exists, use --force to overwrite

When I added --force to the command, I got another error:
Error: Get "https://api.exercism.org/v1/solutions/latest?exercise_id=hello-world&track_id=python": EOF

How can I successfully download this exercise into my GitHub repository folder?

The first and second error sound unrelated. EOF usually stands for "End of File", meaning  for example that the datastream stopped before it was expected to stop. (I am not familiar with exercism though)

You can easily clone a GitHub repository into the folder where Exercism downloads its exercises. Since Git interactions are managed through the .git folder inside the project, you can safely rename the folder to "exercism." From this point onward, Exercism exercises will be downloaded into this directory.
